# org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: Could not retrieve the execution result

Tags: apache-flink, amazon-emr

I am trying to start a Flink batch job on an AWS EMR cluster and am getting:

```
The program finished with the following exception:

org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: Could not retrieve the execution result. (JobID: c7362754c49bdae8e9a46748d47bc180)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.rest.RestClusterClient.submitJob(RestClusterClient.java:260)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:486)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:474)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ContextEnvironment.execute(ContextEnvironment.java:62)
    at com.stolencamerafinder.flink.BatchJob.main(BatchJob.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:529)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:421)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:426)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:804)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.runProgram(CliFrontend.java:280)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:215)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseParameters(CliFrontend.java:1044)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$main$11(CliFrontend.java:1120)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1844)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.HadoopSecurityContext.runSecured(HadoopSecurityContext.java:41)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1120)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionException: Failed to submit JobGraph.
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.rest.RestClusterClient.lambda$submitJob$8(RestClusterClient.java:379)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:870)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniExceptionally.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:852)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1977)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils.lambda$retryOperationWithDelay$5(FutureUtils.java:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:760)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:736)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postFire(CompletableFuture.java:561)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:929)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(CompletableFuture.java:442)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils$RetryException: Could not complete the operation. Exception is not retryable.
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeRelay(CompletableFuture.java:326)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeRelay(CompletableFuture.java:338)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniRelay(CompletableFuture.java:911)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniRelay.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:899)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils$RetryException: Could not complete the operation. Exception is not retryable.
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.util.RestClientException: [Job submission failed.]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeRelay(CompletableFuture.java:326)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeRelay(CompletableFuture.java:338)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniRelay(CompletableFuture.java:911)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniCompose(CompletableFuture.java:953)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:926)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.util.RestClientException: [Job submission failed.]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.RestClient.parseResponse(RestClient.java:310)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.RestClient.lambda$submitRequest$3(RestClient.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniCompose(CompletableFuture.java:952)
    ... 5 more
```

I have no idea of what the underlying cause is. Where can I find more details on why it went wrong?

On a similar note, I can't find a way of finding the logs for a successful job with Flink / EMR. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find more details, you need more information of the JobManager or ResourceManager. If you are using YARN as the cluster resource management framework, which many developers do, you can access to the ApplciationMatser's logs, which are the logs from JobManager in Flink.

Answer (score 2):

I met the same problem, the reason is that I don't have start the flink cluster.

```
./bin/start-cluster.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

i met this problem in my local mac pc, in local mode.
it runs well in maven project, but throws exception above when submitted to flink local cluster.

it was fixed after restarting my macbook